# Ugly linebreak in texniccenter

Tags: line-breaking, texniccenter

After the update some weeks ago to the new version of the texniccenter editor, the linebreaks have become very ugly. For instance, if ''... is positive.'' does not fit in the line, then before it became ''... is [linebreak] positive.''. Now it can become ''... is posit [linebreak] ive.'' or ''... is positive [linebreak].''. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Ins't this just word wrap in TC. Have a look in the configuration. One advise, if available choose *hard wrap* this give IMO the most readable source code, especially when exchanged with others using different editors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! To clarify, this is the line wrapping in the editor itself? (Not in the generated PDF.)

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the code in the editor. The PDF looks fine. I don't find any choice of "hard wrap" or something similar. Where do you set these things?

Comment: I cannot confirm this here, but maybe with a certain setting this happens (try changing entries in menu “View”). Then a bug tracker entry would be useful.

Comment: Under View you can put Word Wrap on or off. It was on, but with off you don't get nice line-breaking but instead one very long line that doesn't fit the screen.

Comment: Once again: I have line breaking activated and do not see this behaviour.